# is it possible to use c# GUI toolbox in an XNA app?

Tags: xna, c#, gui

I need both reach GUI features of c# toolboxes and fast rendering features of XNA, is there any way to merge these two into one app? or is there any other way? for example some equivalent to c# toolbox in xna?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Windows Forms when you talk about "GUI toolbox". There are two samples available in the App Hub to mix XNA rendering with standard controls:

- [Drawing inside a window](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)
- [Loading content from an embedded Game](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)

*(but you lose Xbox360/Win7 Phone/Zune compatibility)*

If you are looking for a GUI library for XNA, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909671/ui-library-for-xna) from Stack Exchange.

Comment: That SE post is a little outdated. Nowadays [NeoForce Controls](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/) is gaining popularity as an in-XNA-Game GUI.

Comment: @CC Ricers First line in the Notes: "this project is no longer maintained or developed" :/

Comment: Yeah, I know and it's a shame that it's stopped, but there's still enough support for it from others to provide some tutorials.

Comment: First link is now broken due to Microsoft changing their website around. Does anyone know how to access these old links?

Comment: @AdamKDean fixed the links; if this happens to you again, just change the main URL to "xbox.create.msdn.com".

Comment: 'If you are looking for a GUI library for XNA, take a look at this post from Stack Exchange" no take a look at this post which is actively maintained http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx.

Comment: @r2d2rigo thanks, just learnt from another thread that you fix them by adding xbox as a subdomain. Great to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/about/). It's an in-game webpage rendering engine based on the Chromium browser (i.e. Google Chrome). You can use HTML/CSS/JavaScript to build your UI widgets that can communicate with your code. If you know a little bit of web design it's a great choice. Might be overkill depending on your project though.

Here's a couple of video showcasing XNA + Awesomium:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5mCWkGXoBs

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PDyAoKAfxk

Comment: I'd second the suggestion to look at Awesomium. It has worked really well for me. I did a blog post on my use of it, and in it there is a link to some helper code I wrote to make the process much, much easier: [http://devblog.drheinous.com/2012/08/on-xna-and-uis.html](http://devblog.drheinous.com/2012/08/on-xna-and-uis.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming for Windows Phone 7, the new Mango update of the OS adds support for XNA games inside a Silverlight application. This way you can create the menus and GUI in Silverlight, and lauch the game inside a frame.
It is expected that Microsoft will sometime soon implement this feature on the PC and Xbox360 versions of XNA, but there's nothing official so far.

Check this article: [XNA for Silverlight developers](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-12-Mango-1.aspx)

Comment: I'm targeting for Windows. but thinking of xna inside silverlight app, really seems tempting.